# matched filter of chirp signals

Tags: matched-filter, linear-chirp

In simulating linear frequency modulated (LFM) chirp signals, with the parameters: 
Pulse width, bandwidth.

I find the matched filter response to be this:

[image]

In particular, there is a increase in the energy over the right side of the plot.

My question is, is this normal, or should the tapering be going down?

Comment: think about this: since your pulse shaper is constant envelope (right?), your MF should be, too. The fact that you're seeing intensity variations at all is probably because of your analysis methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the reason for the spike on the right is due to the inclusion of pulse width of time along the time axis.

Comment: where is this spike on the right?  it looks like it should be just touching the bump on the right.  where is Nyquist in this frequency-domain plot?  this chirp signal must've been windowed with a window of some sort.  it looks a little Hannish or Hammish.  And it looks like the window closed before the frequency changed a lot (or is the spike at DC)?  Turns out that if you're doing linearly-swept frequency chirps, windowing them with a Gaussian window allows for some mathematical properties that can be made use of.

Comment: a while ago [i did another answer that discusses the ideal continuous-time model of a linearly-swept chirp with a gaussian window](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/24191/stft-multiplied-with-gaussian-window-vs-stft-multiplied-by-rectangular-window/36797#36797).

Comment: thanks! the "spike" refers to the gradually elevating response on the right side of the plot. Also, the plot x-axis is in time domain, and i simulated the chirps with rectangular windowing