# Fourier transform of a delayed LFM chirp

Tags: fourier-transform, delay, linear-chirp

I know that for a given signal $s(t)$ and a given delay $ \tau $, by the shift theorem:
$$ \mathcal{F}\{s(t-\tau)(f) \} = e^{-j 2 \pi f \tau} \mathcal{F}\{s(t)(f)  \} \tag{1} $$
However, when I try to derive the Fourier Transform of a delayed LFM chirp, written as:

$$ s_{LFM}(t-\tau) = A e^{j (\omega_o (t-\tau) + \alpha (t-\tau)^2)} \Pi_{\frac{T}{2}}(t-\tau) $$ it gives:

$$ s_{LFM}(t-\tau) = A e^{j( \omega_o (t-\tau) + \alpha (t-\tau)^2)} \Pi_{\frac{T}{2}}(t-\tau) \\ = A e^{j \omega_o t} \ e^{-j \omega_o \tau}  e^{j \alpha t^2} e^{j \alpha \tau^2} e^{j \alpha 2t\tau} \Pi_{\frac{T}{2}}(t-\tau)$$ so:
$$ \mathcal{F}\{s_{LFM}(t-\tau)(f)  \} =  A e^{-j \omega_o \tau} e^{j \alpha {\tau}^2} \ \mathcal{F}\{ e^{j \omega_o t} e^{j \alpha t^2} e^{j \alpha 2t{\tau}} \Pi_{\frac{T}{2}}(t-\tau)(f)  \} \tag{2} $$
The term $ e^{j \alpha 2t{\tau} } $ shifts the spectrum of $s_{LFM}$.

Why do not we get the same result between $(1)$ and $(2)$?

Comment: Are you sure your equation for an LFM chirp is correct? shouldnt $j$ apply to both terms in the exponential? $$Ae^{j \left(\omega_o(t-\tau)+\alpha(t-\tau)^2\right)}$$

Comment: Sorry for the typo, you are right

Comment: I think it does indeed shift the spectrum, but until you include the effects of the $\Pi$ function, aren't you just shifting the spectrum of a rectangle function with infinite support? That is, is there really a difference between $\mathrm{rect}(f / \infty)$ and $\mathrm{rect}((f-2\alpha\tau) / \infty)$?

Comment: Hay you might be interested in [this answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/24191/stft-multiplied-with-gaussian-window-vs-stft-multiplied-by-rectangular-window/36797#36797) or [this one](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/56574/stft-calculation-with-gaussian-window/56583#56583).

Answer (score 2):

Let me get rid of $\Pi_{\frac{T}{2}}(t)$ in the derivation:

$$s(t) = Ae^{j\left(\omega_o t + \alpha t^2\right)}$$

Let's show that $$\mathcal{F}\left\{s(t-\tau)\right\} = e^{-j\omega \tau}\mathcal{F}\left\{s(t)\right\}$$

1. Start with the Fourier Transform of the chirp (*I'm
   omitting the integral's limits, they are $-\infty$ and $\infty$*):
   \begin{align} \mathcal{F}\left\{s(t)\right\} &= \int s(t)e^{-j\omega
   t}dt\\ &= \int Ae^{j\left(\omega_o t + \alpha t^2\right)}e^{-j\omega
   t}dt \end{align}
2. Now let's compute the Fourier Transform of the delayed chirp (notice the substitution $\tilde{t} = t-\tau$):
   \begin{align}
   \mathcal{F}\left\{s(t-\tau)\right\} 
   &=\int s(t-\tau)e^{-j\omega t}dt\\
   &=\int
   Ae^{j\left(\omega_o(t-\tau) + \alpha(t-\tau)^2\right)}e^{-j\omega
   t}dt\\ &= \int Ae^{j\left(\omega_o\tilde{t} +
   \alpha\tilde{t}^2\right)}e^{-j\omega (\tilde{t}+\tau)}d\tilde{t}\\
   &=e^{-j\omega \tau} \int Ae^{j\left(\omega_o\tilde{t} +
   \alpha\tilde{t}^2\right)}e^{-j\omega \tilde{t}}d\tilde{t}\\ &=
   e^{-j\omega \tau}\mathcal{F}\left\{s(t)\right\} \end{align}

Comment: Here the Shift theorem is used, but I was mentioning a direct derivation from the delayed chirp, without the use of that theorem..

Comment: Where do you see the shift theorem being *used*? I use the delayed chirp, compute its Fourier transform (step 2) and show that it indeed equals the Fourier transform of the chirp (step 1) multiplied by $e^{j\omega \tau}$, effectively *deriving* the shift theorem from these two steps.

Comment: @user68882 You should accept this answer to close it out. Jdip addressed your question in it's entirety. He *proved* the time-shift property, he didn't use it directly to show that it works.

Comment: I think the OPs confusion arises from an infinite duration assumption on the LFM. Once the finite nature of the signal is accounted for by the inclusion of the $\Pi$ term, I think the shift will take care of itself. At least I think so.

Comment: I don’t think that’s where the confusion comes from, but I agree that the inclusion of $\Pi$ doesn’t change the derivation.

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring constant terms, the FT of an infinite duration LFM is given by

$$
e^{j\pi\alpha t^2} \leftrightarrow e^{-j\pi f^2/ \alpha}. \tag{1}
$$

Using the delay property of FTs, we know that

$$
e^{j\pi\alpha (t-\tau)^2} =  e^{j\pi\alpha t^2} \ast \delta (t-\tau)\leftrightarrow e^{-j\pi f^2/ \alpha} e^{-j2\pi f \tau}.
\tag{2}
$$

If we expand the phase term of the delayed signal prior to the FT, we get

$$
e^{j\pi\alpha (t-\tau)^2} = e^{j\pi\alpha \tau^2} e^{j\pi\alpha t^2} e^{-j2\pi\alpha t \tau},
\tag{3}
$$

which is the original LFM multiplied by a constant and modulated by the linear phase signal $\exp(-j2\pi \alpha t \tau)$, which, as you correctly point out, must shift the spectrum of original LFM by $-\alpha \tau$. This seems to be the cause of some confusion because a delay in time shouldn't lead to a shift in frequency, but for an LFM it does. This is due to the one-to-one relationship between time and frequency for LFMs.

Let us look at what happens when we shift the spectrum of the undelayed LFM as given in $(1)$ by $-\alpha \tau$:

$$
e^{-j\pi f^2/ \alpha} \rightarrow e^{-j\pi (f + \alpha \tau )^2 / \alpha}
=
e^{-j\pi / \alpha (f^2 + 2 f \alpha \tau + \alpha^2 \tau^2 ) }
=
e^{-j\pi f^2 / \alpha } e^{-j2\pi f \tau} e^{-j\pi \alpha \tau^2},
\tag{4}
$$

which, aside from the constant, is the same as $(2)$. If you went through a careful derivation that accounted for the constant phase terms, you would see that the two are indeed equal.

Comment: Hay you might be interested in [this answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/24191/stft-multiplied-with-gaussian-window-vs-stft-multiplied-by-rectangular-window/36797#36797) or [this one](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/56574/stft-calculation-with-gaussian-window/56583#56583).